# Rolling 12 months SUM from latest available data with varchar YearMonth

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sample Schema: ID (varchar 4), YM (varchar 6), Rev(Float) , P_K (ID,YM)

```
ID      YM      Rev
1001    201112  150
1001    201211  200
1001    201212  200
1001    201303  500
...     ...     ...
1001    201605  400
1023    201112  150
1023    201211  200
1023    201212  200
1023    201303  500
...     ...     ...
1023    201605  700
```

I need to create a VIEW where Every row should have a SUM of Rev (Revenue) for preceeding 12 months from the YM(Year Month).

I have tried the following query, however it returns data from '201512' backwards. Where I was expecting the YM to be starting from '201603' since that is the latest YM data available in the table.

```
 SELECT
    fs.ID,
    fs.YM,
    (SELECT SUM(fsi.Rev) FROM FSource fsi WHERE fsi.YM >= ((100* (fs.YM / 100) + 1)-100) AND fsi.YM <= fs.YM AND fsi.ID= fs.ID) AS Rev

FROM FSource fs
WHERE RIGHT(fs.ym, 2) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FSource fsi WHERE fsi.YM >= ((100* (fs.ym / 100) + 1)-100) AND fsi.YM <= fs.ym AND fsi.ID= fs.ID)
```

Any help, what could possibly be wrong hapenning here?

Expected Output:

```
ID      YM      Rev
...     ...     ...
1001    201601  1500
1001    201602  2400
1001    201603  2400
1001    201604  6000
1001    201605  4800 (assuming last 12 months were 400 each, date range "201506 to 201605")
```

Comment: Create a table that represent 12 months, do left join on this table, ISNULL(sum(yourstuff), 0), group by and that should be it

Comment: Provide desired output.

Comment: And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This is expected output for provided sample data above?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas yes. Remember that provided sample data dates back till '201112' that is very old date.

Comment: Do you expect a single row for each particular month or a single row for each particular pair (ID,YM)?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek , single row for each particular pair (ID,YM) is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this using a correlated subquery:

```
select fs.*,
       (select sum(fs2.rev)
        from fsource fs2
        where fs2.id = fs.id and
              cast(fs2.ym as int) <= cast(fs.ym as int) and
              cast(fs2.ym as int) > cast(fs.ym as int) - 100
       ) as rev_12months
from fsource fs;
```

One problem with your query is this expression `((100* (fs.YM / 100) + 1)-100)`.  For a value such as 201603, it turns into 201501, because SQL Server does integer division.  Also, it is a bad idea to rely on implicit conversion.

The rows being returned are determined by the outer `where`.  I have no idea what that logic is supposed to be doing.

Comment: your solution worked seemlessly. Thanks. Didn't realise it would be that simple. Thanks for elaborating it too.